# Difference between super and this in the commands below?

Tags: java, this, super

What is the difference between these commands when I have a class A and a Class B where B extends A , and they have a common instance variable **size** and the commands below are called from a method **printSize1** inside B?

```
class A {
    protected int size;
}

class B extends A {
    protected int size=7; 

    public void printSize1() {
        System.out.println(((A)this).size)
        System.out.println(super.size);
    }
}
```

Also I have the same question with these two. I have a class A and a class B where B extends A, and they both have a method with the same name **printSize** and an instance variable **size** and the below commands are called from a method **printSize2** inside class B.

```
class A {
    protected int size;

    public void printSize() {
        System.out.println("Size=" + size);
    }
}

class B extends A {
    protected int size=7;

    public void printSize2 {
        ((A) this).printSize();
        super.printSize();
    }

    public void printSize() {
       System.out.println ("MSize="+size);
    }
}
```

Comment: Why don't you just execute the code and see by yourself what the difference is?

Comment: I did it already and the first two have the same output.  In the second situation the first one is using printSize method from class B and the second on is using printSize method from class A. I cannot understand why.

Comment: Then change your question. Tell what the code does, and ask why it does that. Don't ask what the difference is.

Comment: It's also important, when asking for help, to ensure that the code presented compiles (unless the question is "why won't this compile?" of course); the above will not, you're missing `()` in `printSize2`'s declaration. Similarly, using consistent and reasonably standard indentation and bracing makes it easier for people to help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> i have a class A and a Class B where B extends A which they have a common instance variable **size**

No, they don't. They have **separate** instance variables called `size`. One is in the part of the object associated with A, and the other is in the part of the object associated with B. Let's call them `A$size` and `B$size`. For them to have a *common* instance variable, you'd remove the declaration of `size` from `B` so they're both using `A$size`.

Redeclaring an ancestor's non-`private` instance variable (field) is always a bad idea, because it leads to this sort of confusion.

Both of the below output `0` for your example code, because they're both accessing `A$size`, which you never assign a value to, so it has the default value `0`:

```
System.out.println(((A)this).size);  // 0
System.out.println(super.size);      // 0
```

So the question is: *Why* are they both using `A$size` and not `B$size`? Because of the *type* of the reference we're using to look up `size`. In both cases, the type of the reference is `A`, because the type of `(A)this` is `A` (via cast) and the type of `super` in a method in `B` is also `A`. Since the type of the reference is `A`, it's `A`'s `size` that gets used.

In this *particular* case there isn't much of a difference between the two, but there would be if you added another layer to the hierarchy:

```
class A {
    protected int size = 1;
}
class B extends A {
    protected int size = 2;
}
class C extends B {
    protected int size = 3;

    void printSize() {
        System.out.println(((A)this).size);  // 1
        System.out.println(super.size);      // 2
        System.out.println(this.size);       // 3
    }
}
```

Moral of the story: Don't redeclare instance variables declared by an ancestor (unless the ancestor's version is `private`).

Note that this is *different* for variables than it is for methods. Instance methods are polymorphic. Instance variables are not. With methods, you get the method associated with the final type of the object (unless you use `super` or a qualified `super`, because those are special and bypass polymorphism).

This is what's coming into play in your second example in `printSize2`. Because methods are polymorphic, it doesn't matter that you've cast `this` to be type `A` in `((A)this).printSize()`, you still get `B`'s `printSize`. But `super.printSize()` is special because `super` is special and bypasses polymorphism, giving `B` access to `A`'s `printSize`.

Comment: I meant common instance variable name but i understand. The code also has some constructors that i haven't posted. The difference between the second ones why do they occur?

Comment: @Kjssplass: I added a paragraph at the end to explain that. (I'd previously added one to explain that variables and methods are different, but hadn't directly addressed your example.)